# How to show objects count in Django template

Tags: django

I have a program that post some places and shows them in a HTML template, but I also want to show the users many of these places I have and I'm wondering how I can reach this.

I have in my models.py:

```
class Places(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
     text=models.TextField()
     website=models.URLField()
     published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

in views.py:

```
def places(request):
     places=Places.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:10]
     return render(request, 'templates/places.html', {'places':places})
```

and the html template:

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Places<span class="badge"> HERE'S WHERE I WANT THE NUMBER OF PLACES</h2>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me out. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You can't get the count of objects in django's template without writing a custom tag.</strike>

Even if you could however it would be 10, since you especially said places to only include 10 objects.

You should instead pass `places_count` via the context to the template:

```
def places(request):
    places = Places.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:10]
    places_count = Places.objects.count()
    return render(
        request, 'templates/places.html', {'places':places, 'places_count': places_count}
    )
```

And then in the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Places <span class="badge">{{ places_count }}</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this template filter:

```
{{ places|length }}
```

[Documentation link length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#length)

> Don’t overuse count() and exists()

[Optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-count-and-exists)

Comment: Not problem, but i think you should use this solution, because [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-count-and-exists) for no additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

On the htmlpage;

```
{% if products %}
    Number of products: {{ products|length }}
{% else %}
    No products.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).